# Ajax read PHP generated json

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

So I want to send a json to an ajax call but I don't know how to read the json when is sent. And also my json looks strange because of the backslashes...

This is my ajax:

```
    function find(){
        var type = $('#object_type').val();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'get_user.php',
                data : {
                    'type' : type
                },
                dataType : 'json',
                error : function(response){
                    alert('SOMETHING WENT WRONG');
                },
                success : function(response){

This is what I get as a response:
"[{\"name\":\"Test\",\"link\":\"test.php\"},{\"name\":\"Test2\",\"link\":\"test2
.php\"}]"
                }
            });     
    }
```

This is my PHP function:

```
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $user_array;
    $user = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name,link FROM user WHERE `type` LIKE '%".$type."%'") or die();

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
                $row_array['link'] = $row['link'];
                array_push($user_array, $row_array);
            }
        mysqli_close($conn);
        $result = json_encode($user_array, 128);
        echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: The response is probably valid. But is rendered this way. If you look at your dev tool (F12) in your browser you can see the actual respone text in the network tab.

Comment: Mah I don't know if it is really, I read that this backslashes can cause problems..and anyway I don't know how to access the data inside json..

Comment: Try doing this in your success function to see if it works: `alert(response[0].name)`

Comment: I use FireBug and the response in HTML is the as the response I wrote in my question..

Comment: As an aside from the main issue at hand, you should probably add the content type header `header('Content-Type: application/json');`. While not required, it is better to explicitly state this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/ for more details...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First change that you should make :
You don't need to encode two times

```
$result = json_encode($user_array, 128);
echo json_encode($result);
```

should be

```
 $result = json_encode($user_array, 128);
 echo $result;
```

Now the response should look like

```
[{"name":"Test","link":"test.php"},{"name":"Test2","link":"test2
.php"}]
```

which is a valid Javascript Array and can be accessed using following code :

```
var len = response.length;
for(i=0;i<len;i++){

  console.log(response[i].name);
  console.log(response[i].link);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

As provided in *techierishi*'s answer. Do not encode your response twice. Just do

```
 echo $result;
```

The JSON should be valid and parsed, why?

- `json_encode` is used on a valid PHP array returned from a MySQLi query.
- `dataType` is used, explicitly forcing jQuery to `JSON.parse` the response and no errors where raised during that process.

The JSON that is returned has the following structure

```
ROOT
   ARRAY
       ARRAY OBJECT
             OBJECT PROPERTY
```

To address something like that:

```
root[array index].property
```

Will give you the array's value, which is an object. That object has multiple properties.

`[]` means array 
`{}` means object

So `[{name:"value 1"},{name:"value 2"}]` is actually

```
ARRAY
   [0].name = value 1
   [1].name = value 2
```

So retrieving information like name from your JSON will be:

```
response[0].name; // = test
```

Comment: If I do var name = response[0].name;  and then alert(name), I get Undefined

Comment: See Techierishi's answer and the approriate edit I've made to my answer.